# Getting vim-latex to compile using xelatex

Tags: vim, xelatex

Up until recently, my primary device ran Ubuntu (15.x) with VIM (7.x), TeX Live (2016), and `vim-latex`. Since all my files call `fontspec`, my `~/.vimrc` contained these lines:

```
filetype plugin on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'xelatex --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape $*'
```

allowing me to compile using `xelatex` from VIM by typing `\ll` in normal mode. This worked.

I've now installed Arch (kernel release 4.14.7-1) on new hardware, installed the `gvim` (VIM 8.0.1415), `texlive-most` (TeX Live 2017), and `vim-latexsuite` (1:1.9.0-2) packages from repo. I've cobbled together a new `.vimrc` and included the above lines, and nothing that cancels them out. I can successfully compile from the command line running the command defined in the Tex_CompileRule (i.e. `xelatex --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape filename`). I can also compile from VIM by running `:r! xelatex --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape filename`. However, `\ll` executes `pdflatex` instead, which fails because my `tex` file contains the line `\usepackage{fontspec}`. I need it to run `xelatex`. Is there a typo in my `Tex_CompileRule`? Is there some other way to select my typesetting engine? What am I missing?

To be clear, I've restarted VIM since modifying `.vimrc` and checked that the `CompileRule` has been processed by entering `:echo Tex_CompileRule_pdf`, which echoes the desired `xelatex` syntax back at me. I've seen a thread suggesting my `tex_flavor` should be set to `xelatex` rather than `latex`, but that yields the same result. The default output format is obviously PDF, or it wouldn't execute `pdflatex`.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, my workaround has been to use [`vimtex`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) instead; it relies on `latexmk`, which defines the typesetting engine in [`~/.latexmkrc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk?lang=en).